# SQL query won't run when using Group By

Tags: sql, group-by, max, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to write an SQL query that displays the date of the most recent invoice sent to a client. Having read around, using a `MAX()` aggregate function and `GROUP BY` seems to be the way to go.

However, my query is throwing up an error. I've tried grouping by just the function (as seen in the code below), and grouping by everything, but neither works.

SQL is:

```
SELECT
    ClientSupplier.ClientID AS ClientID,
    ClientSupplier.ContactID AS ContactID,
    ClientSupplier.ClientCode AS ClientCode,
    Contact.Pref AS Pref,
    Contact.FName AS FName,
    Contact.LName AS LName,
    ContactPartnerHistory.PartnerID AS PartnerID,
    ContactPartnerHistory.EndDate AS EndDate,
    Partner.PartnerID AS PartnerID2,
    Partner.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
    Employee.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID2,
    Employee.PrefTemp AS PrefTemp,
    Employee.FNameTemp AS FNameTemp,
    Employee.SNameTemp AS SNameTemp,
    Bill.BillToClientID AS BillToClientID,
    Bill.InvoiceDate AS InvoiceDate,
    Max(Bill.InvoiceDate) AS MostRecentInvoiceDate
FROM
    Bill 
INNER JOIN 
    (ClientSupplier 
INNER JOIN 
    (Contact 
INNER JOIN 
    (ContactPartnerHistory 
INNER JOIN 
    (Partner 
INNER JOIN 
    Employee ON Partner.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID) 
  ON Partner.PartnerID = ContactPartnerHistory.PartnerID) 
  ON Contact.ContactID = ContactPartnerHistory.ContactId) 
  ON Contact.ContactID = ClientSupplier.ContactID) 
  ON ClientSupplier.ClientID = Bill.BillToClientID
WHERE
   ClientSupplier.ClientCode NOT LIKE '%zz%' 
   AND ContactPartnerHistory.EndDate IS NULL 
   AND Employee.SNameTemp LIKE '%payroll%'
GROUP BY
   Max(Bill.InvoiceDate)
```

I've [checked the answers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=is%20invalid%20because%20it%20is%20not%20contained%20in%20either%20an%20aggregate%20function&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-GB&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=6tKWU8_eMMPR8gfg5oGoBw&gws_rd=ssl#q=is%20invalid%20because%20it%20is%20not%20contained%20in%20either%20an%20aggregate%20function%20site%3astackoverflow.com&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-GB&safe=active) on here regrading the error message I'm getting, but they seem to suggest that including everything in the group would clear it up, which it doesn't.

The query runs if I exclude the function altogether (and shows all invoice dates), but that's not what I want. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your query, you misunderstood a little what `group by` actually does. You have some columns in which repeating values may occur. And you have one or more columns on which you want to apply an aggregate function to get the sum or the maximum or whatever. `group by` collapses those columns that you specify in the `group by` and applies the aggregate function to the rows in each group.

So, what you should not do, is, to apply an aggregate function to a column that you're grouping by, especially not in the `group by` clause.

```
SELECT
ClientSupplier.ClientID AS ClientID,
ClientSupplier.ContactID AS ContactID,
ClientSupplier.ClientCode AS ClientCode,
Contact.Pref AS Pref,
Contact.FName AS FName,
Contact.LName AS LName,
ContactPartnerHistory.PartnerID AS PartnerID,
ContactPartnerHistory.EndDate AS EndDate,
Partner.PartnerID AS PartnerID2,
Partner.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
Employee.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID2,
Employee.PrefTemp AS PrefTemp,
Employee.FNameTemp AS FNameTemp,
Employee.SNameTemp AS SNameTemp,
Bill.BillToClientID AS BillToClientID,
Bill.InvoiceDate AS InvoiceDate,
Max(Bill.InvoiceDate) AS MostRecentInvoiceDate
FROM
    Bill INNER JOIN (ClientSupplier INNER JOIN (Contact INNER JOIN (ContactPartnerHistory INNER JOIN (Partner INNER JOIN Employee ON Partner.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID) ON Partner.PartnerID = ContactPartnerHistory.PartnerID) ON Contact.ContactID = ContactPartnerHistory.ContactId) ON Contact.ContactID = ClientSupplier.ContactID) ON ClientSupplier.ClientID = Bill.BillToClientID
WHERE
    ClientSupplier.ClientCode NOT LIKE '%zz%' AND ContactPartnerHistory.EndDate IS NULL AND Employee.SNameTemp LIKE '%payroll%'
GROUP BY
ClientSupplier.ClientID AS ClientID,
ClientSupplier.ContactID AS ContactID,
ClientSupplier.ClientCode AS ClientCode,
Contact.Pref AS Pref,
Contact.FName AS FName,
Contact.LName AS LName,
ContactPartnerHistory.PartnerID AS PartnerID,
ContactPartnerHistory.EndDate AS EndDate,
Partner.PartnerID AS PartnerID2,
Partner.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
Employee.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID2,
Employee.PrefTemp AS PrefTemp,
Employee.FNameTemp AS FNameTemp,
Employee.SNameTemp AS SNameTemp,
Bill.BillToClientID AS BillToClientID,
Bill.InvoiceDate AS InvoiceDate
```

You should include all columns that you're `select`ing but that don't have an aggregate function applied to it. That's what the error says.

MySQL allows to not follow above rule (if not prohibitted by your administrator by setting an sql-mode), but keep in mind, that then a random row of each group is displayed.

If you don't want to `group by` all these columns, there's [this very usefull manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html) (that's also applieable to other RDBMS) that explains how to get the row corresponding to the maximum value of each group.

Comment: Thanks - yep, I was looking at it cockeyed.

Comment: I also excluded Invoice date as that was breaking the Group and just went with the function.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
ClientSupplier.ClientID AS ClientID,
ClientSupplier.ContactID AS ContactID,
ClientSupplier.ClientCode AS ClientCode,
Contact.Pref AS Pref,
Contact.FName AS FName,
Contact.LName AS LName,
ContactPartnerHistory.PartnerID AS PartnerID,
ContactPartnerHistory.EndDate AS EndDate,
Partner.PartnerID AS PartnerID2,
Partner.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
Employee.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID2,
Employee.PrefTemp AS PrefTemp,
Employee.FNameTemp AS FNameTemp,
Employee.SNameTemp AS SNameTemp,
Bill.BillToClientID AS BillToClientID,
Bill.InvoiceDate AS InvoiceDate,
Max(Bill.InvoiceDate) AS MostRecentInvoiceDate
FROM
Bill INNER JOIN (ClientSupplier INNER JOIN (Contact INNER JOIN (ContactPartnerHistory INNER JOIN (Partner INNER JOIN Employee ON Partner.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID) ON Partner.PartnerID = ContactPartnerHistory.PartnerID) ON Contact.ContactID = ContactPartnerHistory.ContactId) ON Contact.ContactID = ClientSupplier.ContactID) ON ClientSupplier.ClientID = Bill.BillToClientID
WHERE
ClientSupplier.ClientCode NOT LIKE '%zz%' AND ContactPartnerHistory.EndDate IS NULL 
AND Employee.SNameTemp LIKE '%payroll%'
GROUP BY
ClientSupplier.ClientID AS ClientID,
ClientSupplier.ContactID AS ContactID,
ClientSupplier.ClientCode AS ClientCode,
Contact.Pref AS Pref,
Contact.FName AS FName,
Contact.LName AS LName,
ContactPartnerHistory.PartnerID AS PartnerID,
ContactPartnerHistory.EndDate AS EndDate,
Partner.PartnerID AS PartnerID2,
Partner.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
Employee.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID2,
Employee.PrefTemp AS PrefTemp,
Employee.FNameTemp AS FNameTemp,
Employee.SNameTemp AS SNameTemp,
Bill.BillToClientID AS BillToClientID,
Bill.InvoiceDate AS InvoiceDate
```

Always try to keep 1 thing in the mind that when you are using a aggregate function with other columns, bind all other columns with group by clause.

Comment: You provided a wrong answer. Then, when my answer gets accepted you copy my answer. For what? This site is no game where we play for reputation points. The points serve the purpose to help keeping the site clean by encouraging people to delete wrong/redundant answers. You will get your lost reputation back if you do so by the way.